# R package: travis CI error

Tags: r, travis-ci, bioconductor

I am receiving the following error for my R package called `OPWpaper` from Travis-CI. Can anyone tell me how do I fix that?

```
"Rscript -e 'deps <- devtools::dev_package_deps(dependencies = NA);devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE);if (!all(deps$package %in% installed.packages())) { message("missing: ", paste(setdiff(deps$package, installed.packages()), collapse=", ")); q(status = 1, save = "no")}'" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Note that, my `.travis.yml` file is:

```
# R for travis: see documentation at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r
language: r
sudo: false
cache: packages

r:
  - devel

warnings_are_errors: true
bioc_required: true
bioc_use_devel: true

r_github_packages:
  - jimhester/covr
bioc_packages:
  - BiocCheck

after_script:
  - Rscript -e 'covr::codecov()'
  - ls -lah
  - FILE=$(ls -1t *.tar.gz | head -n 1)
  - Rscript -e "library(BiocCheck); BiocCheck(\"${FILE}\")"

notifications:
  email:
    on_success: always
    on_failure: always
```

Comment: I don't think you provide enough information to detect what went wrong. You can paste the error/warnings lines from Travis logs. Does your package pass the check in RStudio?

Comment: @amatsuo_net Yes, this passed the check in RStudio. please see the link from travis-CI: https://travis-ci.org/mshasan/OPWpaper/builds/241773859?utm_source=email&utm_medium=notification

Comment: Obviously the issue is `missing: OPWeight` which is not a CRAN package. You need to point a repo with that package in DESCRIPTION FILE.

Comment: I think I figured out what is the problem. I developed another package and this package depends on the previous package, but Travis-ci can not find the previous package because the previous package is on the GitHub not available in the Bioconductor yet. Do you know how to direct Travis-CI to GitHub?

Comment: @amatsuo_net you are correct "OPWeight" is my previous package and the current package "OPWpaper". How do I direct Travis-CI to Github?

Comment: I just would like to let you know that, I finally solved the problem. In my .travis.yml file, I just added my GitHub repository under r_github_packages.